# Google Tink upgrade from 1.2.2 to 1.6.1 causes TLS issues when connecting to Vault?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ssl, hashicorp-vault

I am using the Google Tink Java library and upgrading from version 1.2.2 to 1.6.1 is causing TLS issues when I try to connect to Vault for some reason.

here is the error:
`org.springframework.vault.VaultException: Cannot login using TLS certificates: client certificate must be supplied" type="org.springframework.vault.VaultException">org.springframework.vault.VaultException: Cannot login using TLS certificates: client certificate must be supplied`

I am sure that I am providing the client certificate that it needs and I confirmed it multiple times. I wonder what does Tink even has to do with TLS and why would upgrading google Tink even cause problem for connecting to the Vault.
Any ideas?

thanks!